# How does forever monad work?

Tags: haskell

How does forever monad work?

```
forever :: (Monad m) => m a -> m b
forever a = a >> forever a
```

If I write

```
main = forever $ putStrLn "SAD, I DON'T UNDERSTAND!"
```

forever gets IO (), this isn't function, how can forever repeatedly call putStrLn?

Comment: `main` isn't a function, either. Functions don't do IO in haskell, `IO` actions do.

Comment: IO is simple Monad, advanced applicative

Comment: `forever` is not a monad.

Comment: yes, you are right, it works with monads

Answer (score 12):

From the definition of `forever` function, you can see that it is a standard recursive function.

```
forever :: (Monad m) => m a -> m b
forever a = a >> forever a
```

There is no magic going on there. `forever` is just a recursive function. In your particular case, this is a non terminating one. But whether it becomes a terminating or non terminating depends on how the Monad is defined for that type.

Inspect the type of `>>`, we get:

```
λ> :t (>>)
(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
```

From that you can observe the input `m a` is just ignored. Another way to think about that is that `>>` function just performs the side effect of the first parameter passed to it. In your case the `m a` will correspond to `IO ()` since that is the type of `putStrLn`.

Since IO forms a Monad, `forever` function can also act on `IO` related functions.

Comment: forever is a recursive function, and it igore the value or action on the left of >> and call the right part(forever a ) to continue...

Comment: @wshcdr It ignores the resultant value but executes the side effects.

Comment: `forever` is recursive, but it's only non-terminating for some monadic values. For example, `forever Nothing` quickly evaluates to `Nothing`.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks, updated. It certainly depends on how you define the `Monad` instance for your type.

Answer (score 4):

The distinction to make is that `putStrLn "SAD, I DON'T UNDERSTAND!"` is an *action*, not just a value.  It repeatedly executes that *action*.  Whenever something of type `IO a` is evaluated, it executes its internal actions and then returns something of type `a` wrapped in the `IO` context.  It doesn't have to take a parameter for the action to do something.  For example, look at the [`getCurrentTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.1.4/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html) function from the `time` package.  It just has type `IO UTCTime`, but if you call it several times you'll get different values back, even though it takes no parameters.

Comment: I don't understand. putStrLn return IO (). If IO is filled with function, I understand it. But it's imposible to evaluate empty tuple.

Comment: That isn't a tuple, it's a type usually called unit, that has a single value (). Think of it as null or none. It's still a value in haskell, just not one you can do much with.

Comment: The type `IO ()` indicates that it has some side effects and has no meaningful return value. It's still a value, but that value can only be (), so there isn't much you can do with it. There isn't anything special about it, though, it's the same as `data Void = Void`, but with a different name. You can still do things like `x <- putStrLn "hello"`, in which case x had type () and it's value is (). Since it can't be anything else, it isn't useful to extract that value, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: @Seraph, monads evaluation is implicit and is implemented in instantiation of `Monad` typeclass for the corresponding monad. In particular, `IO ()` can be read as "side-effecting action which returns nothing". The actual value it "returns" is unimportant; side effects here are what matter.

Comment: If I understand it right. Forever gets function which returning IO () and if this function is evaluated, every side effect is executed.

Comment: No, `forever` is passed an action, not a function.  Functions are things with `->` in their type. `forever`'s argument is an IO action in your case, not a function.

Comment: then, myaction :: IO (); myaction = putStrLn "BLAH" isn't function but action ?

Comment: @Seraph Correct, functions have arguments, but `myaction` does not.  It performs a side effect, but it doesn't take any arguments in order to perform that side effect.

Comment: and every action is evaluated when main return root action?

Comment: @Seraph Correct.  `main` is the "ultimate" action, the entire behavior of the program occur inside the definition of `main`.  If it isn't used by `main` (directly) or isn't used by one of the sub-expressions of `main` (indirectly), it isn't executed.

Comment: Many small expressions are assembled into final expression, and then the final expressions is executed. It's the Haskell program flow ?

Comment: "Whenever something of type `IO a` is evaluated, it executes its internal actions and then returns something of type a wrapped in the `IO` context." No, that's just wrong. You're mixing up the concept of *evaluating* an expression of type `IO a`, which returns an action, with the concept of *executing* that action, which is external to the language.